# Error: UserForm(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import FormUserDetails from './FormUserDetails';

export class UserForm extends Component {
  state = {
    Step: 1,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    occupation: '',
    city: '',
    bio: '',
  };

  // next step

  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1,
    });
  };

  // go back to previous

  Step = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1,
    });
  };

  // handle field

  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio } = this.state;
    const values = { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio };

    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <FormUserDetails
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );

      case 2:
        return <h1>FormPersonalDetails</h1>;

      case 3:
        return <h1>Confirm</h1>;

      case 4:
        return <h1>Success</h1>;
    }
  }
}

export default UserForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the initial state this is what you have written

```
state = {
    Step: 1,
```

`Step` is not the same as `step`.

JS is case sensitive. So when it hits render, the value of `step` is `undefined`.

As none of the switch statements pass because of this it returns undefined and you see the error.

Also add a default case just in case as you are using `switch`

```
switch (step) {
      case 1:
        ....
      default: 

         return <div>step does not match</div>
}
```